# Is it safe to grow vegetables in oleander soil?

Tags: vegetables, poisons

In my garden I have a big concrete flower box with two oleanders (the box is approx. 2m L x 1m W x ,5m H)

I decided to remove the oleanders and I plan to grow some vegetables instead (mostly tomatoes).

With the plants I have also removed about a half of the soil in the box and I'm goid to replace it with new soil. But half a cube meter of the old soil is going to lay at the bottom of the box (too hard to remove).

Since oleanders are poisonous is there a chance that the poison has gone from the plant to the remaining soil and could possibly go to the vegetables?

Consider that the the oleanders are at least 30 years old and because the box is closed it has collected all the leaves falling from the trees in all theese years

Furthermore the remaining soil is full of tiny oleander roots I could not remove.